# Conditional network neighbours

Tags: netlogo

I want to select the network neighbours filtered by a `link` attribute rather than a `turtle` attribute. For example, this might be selecting only the closest friends based on a strength score on the friendship link. I could do this by having different `link` `breeds` for close friends, but this would require constantly changing breeds as the condition was or was not required.

Below is an example with a boolean condition.

```
links-own [flag?]

to testme
  clear-all
  ask patches [set pcolor white]
  create-turtles 20
  [ setxy 0.95 * random-xcor 0.95 * random-ycor
    set color black
  ]
  ask n-of 3 turtles [set color red]
  repeat 40
  [ ask one-of turtles
    [ create-link-with one-of other turtles
      [ set flag? random-float 1 < 0.4
        set color ifelse-value flag? [red] [gray]
      ]
    ]    
  ]
;  colour-neighbours
  colour-neighbours2
end

to colour-neighbours
  ask turtles with [color = red ]
  [ ask my-links with [flag?]
    [ ask other-end [ set color blue ]
    ]
  ]
end

to colour-neighbours2
  ask turtles with [color = red ]
  [ ask turtle-set [ other-end ] of my-links with [flag?]
    [ set color blue ]
  ]
end
```

I am currently doing the equivalent of colour-neighbours, but it involves stepping through several contexts. The colour-neighbours2 version is conceptually closer because it is referring directly to the network neighbours. However, because of the `of`, I get a list of neighbours that I then have to convert to an agentset.

This is for teaching and, while both work, they seem very convoluted when compared to the unconditional network neighbourhood with the `link-neighbors` primitive. That is, if I didn't care about the flag, I could simply say `ask link-neighbors [ set color blue ]`.

Is there a more direct way to identify network neighbours conditional on a link attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a more-convoluted (worse?) option that uses an agentset:

```
to colour-neighbours4
  ask turtles with [ color = red ] [
    let flag-links my-links with [flag?]
    ask link-neighbors with [ any? my-links with [ member? self flag-links ] ] [ 
      set color blue 
    ]
  ]  
end
```

Comment: good to see an agentset option, but I think you're correct that it's worse since it introduces `member?`

Answer (score 3):

You already cover most possibilities. Another way to do it would be:

```
to colour-neighbours3
  foreach [ other-end ] of my-links with [ flag? ] [ t ->
    ask t [ set color blue ]
  ]
end
```

I would avoid `colour-neighbours2` because, as you stated, it requires the conversion from a list to an agentset. Whether you should use `colour-neighbours` or `colour-neighbours3` is, I think, a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to thank you for your help or not, I am pretty sure the students would have their brains leak out with `foreach` and anonymous functions. But at least I am convinced there's not a straightforward method that I missed.

Comment: @JenB I think this is the most netlogo-ish way to achieve your result